# error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'store_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: magento-1.9

I just installed a new theme and when I access my store I get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'store_id' in 'where clause'

Trace:
#0 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/community/Soczed/Less/Model/Observer.php(145): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Soczed_Less_Model_Observer->beforeLayoutRender(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Soczed_Less_Model_Observer), 'beforeLayoutRen...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(384): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...')
#14 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#15 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#16 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#17 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#18 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#19 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home/fragrance33/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}

Error log record number: 1067159483280
```

### EDIT

Here is the content of the observer.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 *
 * @category   Soczed
 * @package    Soczed_Less
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2012 Soczed <magento@soczed.com> (Benoît Leulliette <benoit@soczed.com>)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

set_include_path(get_include_path().PS.Mage::getBaseDir('lib').DS.'Soczed'.DS.'less');
require_once('lessc.inc.php');

class Soczed_Less_Model_Observer
{
protected function _getHelper()
{
    return Mage::helper('less');
}

protected function _getConfigHelper()
{
    return Mage::helper('less/config');
}

protected function _checkWritableFile($file)
{
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($file);

    if (empty($pathinfo['dirname']) || !is_writable($pathinfo['dirname'])) {
        return $this->_getHelper()->__('Directory is not writable');
    }
    if (is_file($file) && !is_writable($file)) {
        return $this->_getHelper()->__('File is not writable');
    }

    return true;
}

protected function _getLessVariables($file)
{
    // Base variables
    // @todo complete this array with any variable that could be useful
    $variables = array();

    // Get additional variables
    $response = new Varien_Object(array('less_variables' => array()));

    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'soczed_less_additional_variables',
        array(
            'response'  => $response,
            'file_name' => $file,
        )
    );

    if (is_array($additional = $response->getLessVariables())) {
        $variables = array_merge($variables, $additional);
    }

    return $variables;
}

protected function _getLessFunctions($file)
{
    // Base functions
    // @todo complete this array with any function that could be useful
    $functions = array();

    // Get additional functions
    $response = new Varien_Object(array('less_functions' => array()));

    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'soczed_less_additional_functions',
        array(
            'response'  => $response,
            'file_name' => $file,
        )
    );

    if (is_array($additional = $response->getLessFunctions())) {
        $functions = array_merge($functions, $additional);
    }

    return $functions;
}


public function beforeLayoutRender($observer)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if (!$this->_getConfigHelper()->isEnabled()) {
        return;
    }

    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

    if (($head = $layout->getBlock('head'))
        && ($head instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head)) {
        $baseJsDir     = Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'js' . DS;
        $designPackage = Mage::getDesign();
        $newItems      = $head->getData('items');
        $heading_font  = Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_general/heading_font', $storeId);
        if($heading_font) {
            $heading_font = $heading_font;
        }else{
            $heading_font = "CaviarDreamsRegular";
        }
        $globalVars    = 
        array(
        "heading_font" => $heading_font,
        "l_background_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_background_color', $storeId),
        "l_text_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_text_color', $storeId),
        "l_link_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_link_color', $storeId),
        "l_active_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_active_color', $storeId),
        "l_heading_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_heading_color', $storeId),
        "l_icons_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_icons_color', $storeId),
        "l_buttons_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_buttons_color', $storeId),
        "l_buttons_hover_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_buttons_hover_color', $storeId),
        "l_new_label_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_new_label_color', $storeId),
        "l_sale_label_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_sale_label_color', $storeId),
        "l_easyslider_background_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/l_easyslider_background_color', $storeId),

        "d_background_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_background_color', $storeId),
        "d_text_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_text_color', $storeId),
        "d_link_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_link_color', $storeId),
        "d_active_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_active_color', $storeId),
        "d_heading_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_heading_color', $storeId),
        "d_icons_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_icons_color', $storeId),
        "d_buttons_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_buttons_color', $storeId),
        "d_buttons_hover_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_buttons_hover_color', $storeId),
        "d_new_label_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_new_label_color', $storeId),
        "d_sale_label_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_sale_label_color', $storeId),
        "d_easyslider_background_color" => Mage::getStoreConfig('themeoptions_theming/theme_presets/d_easyslider_background_color', $storeId)
        );
        // Cache by file path
        $filesCollection = Mage::getModel('less/file')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFilter('store_id',$storeId)
            ->load();
        $filesIds = array_flip($filesCollection->toOptionHash());
        foreach ($newItems as $key => $item) {
            if (in_array($item['type'], array('js_css', 'skin_css'))) {
                // CSS file
                if (substr($item['name'], -5) == '.less') {
                    // LESS file
                    if ($item['type'] == 'js_css') {
                        $lessFile = $baseJsDir . $item['name'];
                    } else {
                        $lessFile = $designPackage->getFilename($item['name'], array('_type' => 'skin'));
                    }
                    $baseFile = ltrim(str_replace(Mage::getBaseDir(), '', $lessFile), DS);
                    $cssFile  = substr($lessFile, 0, -5) . '_store'.$storeId.'.css';          
                    //die();            
                    try {
                        // Init file config
                        if (isset($filesIds[$baseFile])) {
                            $isNewModel      = false;
                            $model           = $filesCollection->getItemById($filesIds[$baseFile]);
                            $oldCache        = $model->getCache();
                            $forceRebuild    = (bool)$model->getForceRebuild();
                            $customVars      = $model->getCustomVariables();
                            $useGlobalVars   = (bool)$model->getUseGlobalVariables();
                            $forceGlobalVars = (bool)$model->getForceGlobalVariables();
                        } else {
                            $isNewModel      = true;
                            $model           = null;
                            $oldCache        = null;
                            $forceRebuild    = false;
                            $customVars      = array();
                            $useGlobalVars   = true;
                            $forceGlobalVars = false;
                        }

                        // Get all needed variables for current file
                        if (is_array($customVars)) {
                            $oldVars    = $customVars;
                            $customVars = array();

                            foreach ($oldVars as $oldVar) {
                                $customVars[$oldVar['code']] = $oldVar['value'];
                            }
                        } else {
                            $customVars = array();
                        }
                        if ($useGlobalVars) {
                            $variables  = array_merge(
                                ($forceGlobalVars  ? $customVars : $globalVars),
                                ($forceGlobalVars ? $globalVars : $customVars)
                            );
                        } else {
                            $variables = $customVars;
                        }
                        $variables = array_merge($variables, $this->_getLessVariables($item['name']));

                        // Compile if needed (depends on cache and rebuild flag)
                        $oldCache = (is_array($oldCache) ? $oldCache : $lessFile);

                        try {
                            $newCache = lessc::cexecute(
                                $oldCache,
                                $forceRebuild,
                                $variables,
                                $this->_getLessFunctions($item['name'])
                            );
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            if ($this->_getConfigHelper()->getShowErrors()) {
                                if (!is_string($result = $this->_checkWritableFile($cssFile))) {
                                    file_put_contents($cssFile, "\n/* ".$e->getMessage()." */\n", FILE_APPEND);
                                }
                            }
                            throw $e;
                        }
                        if (!is_array($oldCache) || ($newCache['updated'] > $oldCache['updated'])) {
                            if (!is_string($result = $this->_checkWritableFile($cssFile))) {
                                file_put_contents($cssFile, $newCache['compiled']);
                            } else {
                                Mage::throwException($result);
                            }
                            if ($isNewModel) {
                                $model = Mage::getModel('less/file')->setPath($baseFile);
                            }
                            // Won't be further needed and takes most of the place
                            unset($newCache['compiled']); 
                            $model->setCache($newCache)->save();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::logException($e);
                    }

                    // Force adding the CSS file instead of Less one
                    $newItems[$key]['name'] = substr($item['name'], 0, -5) . '_store'.$storeId.'.css';
                }
            }
        }

        // Replace old items with parsed ones
        $head->setData('items', $newItems);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the content for the error log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:83:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'store_id' in 'where clause'";i:1;s:3157:"#0 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/fragrance33/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/community/Soczed/Less/Model/Observer.php(145): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Soczed_Less_Model_Observer->beforeLayoutRender(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Soczed_Less_Model_Observer), 'beforeLayoutRen...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(384): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...')
#14 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#15 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#16 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#17 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#18 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#19 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home/fragrance33/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home/fragrance33/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Thanks again and sorry for any confusion.

Comment: you have some problem in the file `/app/code/community/Soczed/Less/Model/Observer.php` provide the content inside that file. More over there is a log registered for this. check `var/report/1067159483280.log` and provide content inside it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added the response as an answer since it didn't all fit here.

Comment: dont post edit of your question as answers. You need to make it part of your original question. Fo this you have an `edit` option just below your original question. Use it. At that time delete these two answers

Comment: i edited your question for you. so delete those answers

Comment: Thank you.  I was working on that.  I appreciate your help.  I deleted the other 2 answers.  Sorry for the confussion, I'm new to stackexchange.

Comment: don't leave your question as it is.. Feel free to accept answers if it helped. i know telling anyone to accept my answer is bad..  but for the community you should do it. If you have time, you can answer your own question with much more details of the issue and accept it as answer. No issue for that

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party theme

Answer (score 1):

I am not understanding  why did this theme use obsever to set some data. However the problem resides here. In obeserver there is a part look like this.

```
    // Cache by file path
    $filesCollection = Mage::getModel('less/file')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFilter('store_id',$storeId)
        ->load();
```

Here the part `addFilter()` is not working. Basically what this code does is, it loads a table (not a core table here. Must be a table that is using by the theme itself) and get all rows in that table then trying to filter that collection. For filtering it demands that it need items from the table that has `store_id` set to a special value. However the error tells that, the table do not have such field in it.

So you can do following steps

1. Contact theme developers and raise a ticket based on it
2. try `addFieldToFilter() instead of addFilter()`
3. comment out that line and then try

Comment: Commenting out that line fixed the issue.  I opened a ticket with the developer of that theme to see why that would be and what update may be needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: if you get a better answer from their part, you can post it as an answer and feel free to accept it. Dont leave a question as it is